# posting form data from iframe src

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, iframe

**login.php**

```
<iframe id ="login_iframe" name="login_iframe" src ="iframe.php"></iframe>
```

and in my **iframe.php**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="login_submitform" method="post" action="post.php" target="_top" />
<input type="text" name="customer" value=""/>
<input type = "text" name="phone" value=""/>
<input type= "submit" value="submit" />
```

and in my **post.php** comes the result

```
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
?>
```

RESULT
  customer = empty string
  phone= empty string

what am i doing wrong here? how can i get the form values to post.php. pls assist

Comment: You are making the browser make a GET request (that is what assigning a URL to location.href _does_), and yet you somehow expect to find POST data afterwards …

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you simply want this form to always send the data to `http://samedomain.com/post.php`, so that the result is displayed in the top level window instance, no matter whether this script was called directly or embedded in an iframe? Then simply set that URL as form action, add `target="_top"` to it, and … done.

Comment: tnx u misorude for this information. i have updated the code , yet it stil post empty data.  any clue on hw to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, things to be noted here :
 You can only access data of iframe in same domain, your login.php, iframe.php and post.php must be in same domain, here assuming you are testing on localhost

please restrict your form fields, with required. you are good to go.

```
<form id="login_submitform" method="post" action="post.php" target="_top" />
    Customer: <input type="text" name="customer" value="" required/>
    Phone: <input type = "text" name="phone" value="" required/>
    <input type= "submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

It will not submit if value are empty.

post.php

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo $_POST['customer'] .'<br>';
    echo $_POST['phone'] .'<br>'

?>
```